# How to implement map instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (`req[]`, `res[]`) which need to be compared and the differences should display in log. For this I am using a for loop, but I want to use map for solving this problem.

Note: Need to sort both the arrays first.

```
for(var i=0;i<req.length;i++)
{
    if(req[i]!==res[i])
    {
        console.log('unmatched element  : '+req[i]+' and '+res[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

How can I use map to sort both arrays using some attribute like id or name and then compare both arrays and print error with values when match fails?

Comment: Why do you want to use `map` for this if the loop already works?

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array use Array.sort it sorts the array in place. You pass it a sort function. The sort function takes two arguments (a,b) and returns -1 if `a` is lower than `b`, 0 if the same, 1 if `a` is greater than `b`

```
const arr = "akjdfgeknskhg".split(""); // create an array of characters
arr.sort((a,b)=> a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0);
```

To create an array with a report of matched you can use map to get a one to one map of each item in the arr. Do that for both arrays for the first checking for both matched and unmatched. For the second you dont need to report on matches as that is already done so just do the unmatched and pass a null, undefined empty string what ever does not matter.

Then filter out the nulls and you are done.

```js
   //
    const arr1 = [1,2,5,67,8,4,32,392];
    const arr2 = [1,2,8,4,32,392,76,34,2,44];
    const resArr = [
        ...arr1.map(item => item + (arr2.includes(item) ? " arr1 matched arr2. " : " arr1 unmatched")),
        ...arr2.map(item => !arr1.includes(item) ? item + " arr2 unmatched. " : "")
    ].filter(item => item !== "");
    console.log(resArr);
```